# Discriminant Analysis in Tidymodels

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-parsnip

```
flexible_model <- 
  discrim_flexible( mode = "classification",
                    num_terms = tune(),
                    prod_degree = tune(),
                    prune_method = tune,
                    engine = "earth"
  )

set.seed(123)
flexible_wf <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(flexible_model) %>% 
  add_recipe(model_recipe)
flexible_wf



flexible_results <-
  flexible_wf %>% 
  tune_grid(resamples = heart_cv,
            metrics = metric_set(accuracy)
  )
```

error:

> Fold01: preprocessor 1/1, model 1/10: Error: `prune_method` should be a single string value

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 2):

```
flexible_model <- 
  discrim_flexible( mode = "classification",
                    num_terms = tune(),
                    prod_degree = tune(),
                    prune_method = tune(), # <--- change
                    engine = "earth"
  )
```